# LinkedList poll() of null element in node vs. LinkedList poll() of empty list

Tags: java, queue

I was looking at the code for `poll()` and `unlinkFirst()` in `LinkedList`, and I can't seem to find how it safeguards against returning null if there is a `null` item in the `LinkedList`.

`poll()` is defined in interface `Queue` to return null only if the `Queue` is empty.  `LinkedList` violated the recommendation that Queues not contain `null` elements, since this would prevent `poll()` from working properly - yet I can't see any alternate return value for `poll()` if the node contains a null element.

I would have thought that a widely-used class like this would either remove the `poll()` method, or account for this error point somehow.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

> `poll()` is defined in interface `Queue` to return null only if the Queue is empty

No it isn't. "Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, or returns null if this queue is empty.". There is no "only" there.

> `LinkedList` violated the recommendation that `Queues` not contain null elements

There is no such recommendation and no violation. There is a statement that "Even in the implementations that permit it, null should not be inserted into a Queue", but that's addressed to user programmers, not to the implementations.